# How to get base64 from web and decode in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I'm new in Swift and  I am searching for a long time on net, but no use.

I would like to decode base64 that from web server and I'm sure the base64 Data is correct but I can't convert to image.

> This is base64 string

[enter link description here](https://github.com/Jeff12280/JeffData/projects)

And this is my code

```
Alamofire.request("http://www.MyWebService//MyWebService/MyWebService.asmx/MyWebService").response { response in
            print("Request: \(response.request)")
            print("Response: \(response.response)")
            print("Error: \(response.error)")

            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
                self.getdata(data: data)
            }
        }
 func getdata(data: Data)
    {
        let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
        parser.delegate = self
        guard parser.parse() else {
            print("xml parse error: \(parser.parserError?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        // get the parsedXMLString from
        guard let value = parsedXMLString, let jsonData = value.data(using: .utf8) else {
            print("cannot convert to data")
            print("string: \(parsedElementValue)")
            return
        }
        print("jsondata:\(jsonData)")
        // try now parsing the JSON body
        do {
            if let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String]]{
                self.XmlImage = jsonArray!
                print("data:\(self.XmlImage)")
            }
            else {
                print("data didn't get")
            }
        }
    }
extension ViewController: XMLParserDelegate {
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if  elementName == "string"
        {
            parsedElementValue = ""
        }
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        parsedElementValue?.append(string)
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "string" {
            parsedXMLString = parsedElementValue
            parsedElementValue = nil
        }
    }
}
```

the XmlImage is get **"data didn't get"**. I can't download the photo because this is for iOS.

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For that best prectice you need to only send image url in response. But from your current case you can follow the below steps.

To get image from base64 string. First you need to get data from base64 and from that data you can create an image.

**Step1:** Get Data from base64

```
let encodedImageData = ... web base64 string ...
let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedImageData options: .allZeros)
```

**Step2:** Get Image from Data

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

**Step3:** Set Image to your UIImageView.

```
imageView.image = image
```